# How to use local p2 site to solve dependency issue in RCP application development?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm new to RCP development. Here is my problem.

1. First the following sreenshot is my directroy structure.
   [image]
2. I want to use [Unirest for Java](http://unirest.io/java.html) in my plug-in project, which is **com.example.e4.rcp.todo** in our case.
3. I follow [this](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin) runs a **p2 update site** locally by `mvn jetty:run` successfully, and I added following line into `<artifacts>`

   ```
   <artifact><id>com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9</id></artifact>
   ```
4. And now I want to use **Maven** to build my project through [Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/). Here are my **pom.xml**, which under **com.example.e4.rcp.todo** directory.

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.example.e4.rcp</groupId>
     <artifactId>com.example.e4.rcp.todo</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

     <repositories>  
       <repository>  
         <id>neon</id>  
         <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon</url>  
         <layout>p2</layout>  
       </repository>     
     </repositories>  

     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
           <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.26.0</version>
           <extensions>true</extensions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>  
           <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>  
           <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>  
           <version>0.26.0</version>  
         </plugin>            
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
           <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
           <version>0.26.0</version>
           <configuration>
             <environments>
               <environment>
                 <os>linux</os>
                 <ws>gtk</ws>
                 <arch>x86</arch>
               </environment>
               <!-- and others... -->
             </environments>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </project>
   ```

   5. When I run `mvn clean package`, it shows the following error:

> [ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies: [ERROR]   Software being
>   installed: com.example.e4.rcp.todo 1.0.0.qualifier [ERROR]   Missing
>   requirement: com.example.e4.rcp.todo 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle
>   com.mashape.unirest.java 1.4.9' but it could not be found [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] See
>   http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting
>   for help. [ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject:
>   com.example.e4.rcp:com.example.e4.rcp.todo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @
>   C:\Users\wangzen\workspace2\com.example.e4.rcp.todo\pom.xml: See log
>   for details -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of
>   the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven
>   using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For
>   more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
>   the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException

What should I do to solve this problem? Do I have to add the local p2 update site into **pom.xml**?

**BTW**: I'd really appreciate it if anyone who can help me to format my question description, especially in **pom.xml** section. I've tried using `<code>` block, but it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
<repository>
  <id>unirest</id>
  <url>file:/path/to/unirest/p2/repo</url> <!-- or an http:// based one if available -->
  <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

Comment: Yes, this way works. What I want is through `http` though.

Comment: And for the `<id>` part, is an arbitrary **id** okay for it ? like you use `unirest`.

Comment: Yes, `<id>` is arbitraty.

Comment: If you want http, either use the URL created by your `jetty:run` or consider moving the content of the p2 repo you created for unirest somewhere on the web to access it remotely (and universally)

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. the local p2 update site is `http://localhost:8080/site`, however when I run `mvn clean install`. it shows the message, `[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'unirest' from location http://localhost:8080/site/: No repository found at http://localhost:8080/site. -> [Help 1]`